# CAPL: Create a lookup table, that assigns values to a changing variable

Tags: variable-assignment, lookup-tables, capl, canoe, canalyzer

I want to assign a value to a variable in CANoe by using a lookup table.

If sysvar:test changes to the values 1, 2 or 3, then I want that sysvar::show changes to the values 4, 78 and 33 or other values I assign. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some, to show the community your efforts.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? How to react on a sysvar change, how to change a sysvar, how to use an associative array?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good place to start

```
variables
{
  int mapValues[int64];
}

on prestart
{
  mapValues[1] = 4;
  mapValues[2] = 78;
  mapValues[3] = 33;
}

on sysvar test
{
  @sysvar::show = mapValues[@sysvar::test];
}
```